# Generate labels with TCPDF

Tags: html, pdf, tcpdf, label

I want to generate a PDF from HTML using TCPDF to make some labels. (4 per A4 sheet). The thing is that I will not have always just 4...I might have from 1 to 100. In each label a will have a table that will get some details from a mysql db based on a serial number. When I need to have 1 or 2 or 3 labels, I need the other spaces to be empty. I don't know how to do this...print div/table from left to right and then again on the next row. Has anyone done something like this?

```
_____
|1 2|
|3 4|
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Please note that Stackoverflow is not a free coding service

Comment: I completely forgot about this questions. I managed to get it working as I need it and I'll post the answer soon. I know this is not a free or paid coding service, but would of liked an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done to get it working. So, I needed on a A4 sheet 4 labels, and on each label it has 2 tables , one top and one bottom with the middle empty. I have a lot of tables in tables, but it work as I need it. I removed anything related with mysql that am using.

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetMargins(11, 14, 11);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
ob_start();
?><style>
 tr.style10 {line-height: 10pt;}
 tr.style12 {line-height: 12pt;}
 tr.style20 {line-height: 20pt;}
 tr.style30 {line-height: 30pt;}
 tr.style110 {line-height: 110pt;}
 tr.style360 {line-height: 360pt;}
</style>
?>
$x = $start+$quantity-1;
$r = fmod($quantity,2);
for($j=$start;$j<$x;$j+=2){
 $i=$j+1;
 echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
        <tr width=\"100%\">
            <td align=\"center\" width=\"45.5%\">
                <table  width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                    <tr class=\"style\" width=\"100%\">
                        <td align=\"center\">
                            <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                <tr class=\"style2\">
                                    <td>
                                        <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\">
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td width=\"100%\">
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\">".$j."</font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style30\">
                                                <td>
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"40%\"rowspan=\"2\"><img src=\"img/xz.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"50\"></td>
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=\"style110\">
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=\"style2\">
                                    <td>
                                        <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\">
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td width=\"100%\">
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\">".$j."</font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td>
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"40%\"rowspan=\"2\"><img src=\"img/xz.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"50\"></td>
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td width=\"9%\"></td>
            <td align=\"center\" width=\"45.5%\">
                <table  width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                    <tr class=\"style\" width=\"100%\">
                        <td align=\"center\">
                            <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                <tr class=\"style2\">
                                    <td>
                                        <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\">
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td width=\"100%\">
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\">".$i."</font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td>
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"40%\"rowspan=\"2\"><img src=\"img/xz.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"50\"></td>
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=\"style110\">
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=\"style2\">
                                    <td>
                                        <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\">
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td width=\"100%\">
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\">".$i."</font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td>
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"40%\"rowspan=\"2\"><img src=\"img/xz.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"50\"></td>
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br><br><br>";  
}
if($r != 0){
echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
        <tr width=\"100%\">
            <td align=\"center\" width=\"45.5%\">
                <table  width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                    <tr class=\"style\" width=\"100%\">
                        <td align=\"center\">
                            <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                <tr class=\"style2\">
                                    <td>
                                        <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\">
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td width=\"100%\">
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\">".$x."</font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td>
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"40%\"rowspan=\"2\"><img src=\"img/xz.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"50\"></td>
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=\"style110\">
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=\"style2\">
                                    <td>
                                        <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\">
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td width=\"100%\">
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style12\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"12\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\">".$x."</font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                <td  width=\"100%\"><font size=\"10\"></font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class=\"style20\">
                                                <td>
                                                    <table align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"40%\"rowspan=\"2\"><img src=\"img/xz.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"50\"></td>
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"60%\"  align=\"left\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class=\"style10\">
                                                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"8\"></font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td width=\"9%\"></td>
            <td align=\"center\" width=\"45.5%\">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
  }
$html = ob_get_clean();
$pdf->writeHTML($html);
$pdf->Output('your.pdf', 'I');
```